# Handling Asynchronous Call by Alamofire

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

I am using Swift 3 with XCode 8

I am pretty new to IOS development and using Swift. I am currently having a problem where some required code does not run after the asynchronous call has successfully been completed.

In my constants file:

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

In my WeatherVC.swift file:

```
var currentWeather = CurrentWeather()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self
    currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails{
        //setup UI to load downloaded data
        print("Done 2")
        self.updateMainUI()
    }
}
```

In my CurrentWeather.swift class:

```
    func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){
    //Alamofire download
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL)!

    Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
            if let name = dict["name"] as? String{
                self._cityName = name.capitalized
                print(self._cityName)
            }

            if let weather = dict["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
                if let main = weather[0]["main"] as? String{
                    self._weatherType = main.capitalized
                    print(self._weatherType)
                }
            }

            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? Double {
                    let kelvinToCelsius = currentTemperature - 273.15
                    self._currentTemp = kelvinToCelsius
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }
        }
        print("Done 1")
    }
    completed() //Make sure to tell download is done

}}
```

When Executing the code, "Done 2" is being printed out first, before "Done 1", when I want it to be the other way around.

How can I fix this? (FYI: Following Weather App Tutorial on Udemy)

Comment: You need to put your call to `completed` inside the `responseJSON` closure, not after it.

Comment: Wow Thanks, it works now.

Comment: BTW, it's not critical here, but rather than setting the properties for city name, weather type, and current temp properties in here, people would often make those three parsed values as parameters in the `DownloadComplete` `typealias` and then pass those values back when you call `completed`. E.g. `typealias DownloadComplete = (_ city: String?, _ weather: String?, _ temperature: Float?, _ error: Error?) -> Void`. The code performing network requests should probably not be messing around with model objects. You also want to let the caller decide what to do and to identify errors)

Answer (score 0):

Update: It was just simply moving `completed` inside the `responseJSON` closure.